# Installing modules using pip

Tags: python, numpy, command-line, pip, python-3.5

What's the difference between

```
pip install numpy
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade numpy.
```

When I tried to use the first one to install the NumPy module in Python 3.5.2, it wasn't recognised, but when I used the second, there were no problems.

Comment: What system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first expression is used to install a new package, **numpy** in this case, at the last available version (if not specified)

If you want install a particular version, for example the 1.12.0b1, you can use the following command:

```
pip install numpy==1.12.0b1
```

Finally, the --upgrade or -U param, upgrades all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.

upgrade-strategy is another parameter that you can find in the relative [doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options).

Since you don't have added information about errors, is difficult understand what is the real problem. I mean, the expression `it wasn't recognised` and `there were no problems` are not very clear. I suggest you to edit you question with some information.

Anyway, I suppose that you have already installed numpy on your pc, maybe in some past attempt. To verify this run the command:

```
pip freeze
```

and check if there is numpy in the installed package list.

If yes, I think that this is the reason because `pip install numpy` doesn't work and instead `pip install --upgrade numpy` yes. Basically you are not installing numpy but upgrading it, because is already installed.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First expression just verify if module installed. The installation will stop if module has outdated version.
Second expression will install last released or upgrade already installed package to last released version.
More info you can get from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/)